# How to use segment.io's analytics.js in a knockout custom bindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using knockout to make a custom binding for analytics.track, but it seems to be having trouble. It seems if the analytics.track is nested in more than 2 functions the track call fails silently. It doesn't hit the callback and it doesn't report in segments debugger. I have provided 2 examples demonstrating the problem here:

Without Closure (works):

```
function sendTrack(event, props) {
  console.log("Enter sendTrack");
  analytics.track('Signed Up', {
    plan: 'Enterprise'
  }, {}, function () {
    console.log('track callback logged');
  });
}

ko.bindingHandlers.segmentTrack = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    console.log("Init");
    var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { click: sendTrack });
  }
};
ko.applyBindings({});
```

With Closure (doesn't work):

```
(function(ko, $, analytics){
  'use strict';
  function sendTrack(event, props) {
    console.log("Enter sendTrack");
    analytics.track('Signed Up', {
      plan: 'Enterprise'
      }, {}, function () {
        console.log('track callback logged');
      });
  }

  ko.bindingHandlers.segmentTrack = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
      console.log("Init");
      var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
      ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { click: sendTrack });
    }
  };

  ko.applyBindings({});
})(window.ko, window.jQuery, window.analytics);
```

Edit1: Also note this works with if I move the analytics.track to init:

```
(function(ko, $, analytics){
  'use strict';
  ko.bindingHandlers.segmentTrack = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
      console.log("Init");
      analytics.track('Signed Up', {
      plan: 'Enterprise'
      }, {}, function () {
        console.log('track callback logged');
      });
    }
  };

  ko.applyBindings({});
})(window.ko, window.jQuery, window.analytics);
```

Please advise

Comment: Your latest edit invalidated my answer (I'm not sure whether to delete it or leave it there for others who might find use in it). With your latest post however, I think it's impossible for us to tell what's going on. You should create a [mcve] and update the question with that, because currently I'm guessing the problem lies in something (load order, code, etc) not shown in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So analytics.js asynchronously loads its self in the page. In the mean time it queues all calls to the API with a snub version of the object. Once analytics.js loads it executes all the calls in the queue. Then redefines its self, breaking all refs to the original window.analytics. So any calls that are encountered fast enough to  My only work around for this is to make my exposer a function call that returns the current version of the window.analytics.

```
(function (ko, $, analytics) {

    function sendTrack(event, props) {
        analytics().track(event, props);
    }

    ko.bindingHandlers.segmentTrack = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { click: function () { sendTrack(value.event, value.options) }});
        }
    }
})(window.ko, window.jQuery, function () { return window.analytics; });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely because of the order things load / are initialized on the `window` object. Because the iife executes *immediately*, the `analytics` variable will be set to whatever `window.analytics` is *the moment the iife is encountered by the browser*. In the first case, `window.analytics` will be resolved when the code is *run*.

Put differently: the closure captures `window.analytics` in a scoped `analytics` variable *at the time the iife executes*.

Here's a demo showing the problem.

Without closure:

```js
function sendTrack() {
  console.log("Tracking...");
  analytics.track("stuff");
}

ko.bindingHandlers.segmentTrack = { 
  init: function(element) {
    console.log("Init");
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { click: sendTrack });
  }
}

ko.applyBindings({ });

// Simulate loading analytics now:
window.analytics = { track: function(txt) { console.log("Tracking " + txt); } };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="segmentTrack: true">CLICK ME</div>
```

vs with closure:

```js
(function(ko, analytics) {
  function sendTrack() {
    console.log("Tracking...");
    analytics.track("stuff");
  }

  ko.bindingHandlers.segmentTrack = {
    init: function(element) {
      console.log("Init");
      ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { click: sendTrack });
    }
  }

  ko.applyBindings({});
})(window.ko, window.analytics); // window.analytics isn't quite okay yet!

// Simulate loading analytics now:
window.analytics = { track: function(txt) { console.log("Tracking " + txt); } };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="segmentTrack: true">CLICK ME</div>
```

True, in my examples the second scenario throws an error whereas you mention in the question *nothing* happens, but then again the question doesn't contain an actual repro so it's hard to tell where that difference lies.

Comment: I updated my question. I don't understand why a load order issue would effect the code this way?